# Compatibility Watch OS 1, OS 2

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watch, watchos-2

I know an OS 2 app is not compatible for OS 1. But I wonder whether an OS 1 is compatible for OS 2. And what are the best practices ? Develop 2 apps (1 for OS 1, another for OS 2) ? Or an OS 1 app for all ? Or only OS2 app and we ignore users on OS 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

1. WatchOS1 Apps can work on watchOS2. (But, it is too slow. No app can't launch first time successfully before screen dimming).
2. Apple recommends that you should have to develop two watch apps for each os version.

Personally, I recommend that just ignore watch OS1 users:

1. It increases cost but affects so few users.
2. Xcode doesn't support testing for watchOS1 anymore (You need watchOS1 installed watch, or you should have to install old Xcode also)

iTunes Connect will show some warning about it, just ignore it. I think nobody want to use watchOS1. Running 3rd party apps on watchOS1 and watchOS2.0 (not 2.0.1) is just luck. They are almost not usable.